# How to listen for "Example EMF Model Creation Wizards"?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, listener, emf, eclipse-mars

I am developing a plugin for Eclipse Mars.2. I want to know if it is possible to create **Example EMF Model Creation Wizards** file programmatically and add data to the generated model file. Is it possible ?

**EDIT**

I have defined an ecore model that I use to create an Example EMF Model Creation Wizards file but I would like to do that automatically. My problem is that when I generate a file with all the correct data in it, I can't use it and navigate through the data. I have to copy the text data into a file created with the Eclipse wizard to make it work. This file is then interpreted by a Sirius diagram/table definition to create a graphical view.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to listen for the file being created? You use `IResourceChangeListener` for that (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51241766/2670892))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question actually is, so taking it literally I say you can use the EMF APIs to create models programmatically. This has nothing to do with the wizards though.

Comment: I have defined an ecore model that I use to create an Example EMF Model Creation Wizards file but I would like to do that automatically. My problem is that when I generate a file with all the correct data in it, I can't use it and navigate through the data. I have to copy the text data into a file created with the Eclipse wizard to make it work. This file is then interpreted by a Sirius diagram/table definition to create a graphical view.

Comment: Still not sure what you are doing, or trying to do. Can you list the precise steps you are taking and what is going wrong compared to your expectations ?